# How to use JSSOR slider without fixed height and width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jssor

I am using jssor slider for image slider .

I want my images to take whole width but half the height of total screen . I am using the following code 
to resize the image to different screen sizes

```
function ScaleSlider() {      
    var parentWidth = $('#slider1_container').parent().width();     


      if (parentWidth) {
       jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);

   }
   else
       window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
```

My understanding is for JSSOR slider to work I need to provide width and height. I have images of size  1280 X 415. I gave a width width of 1280 and height of 200 for inner and outer slier containers

```
    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1280px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->
    <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1280px; height: 200px;">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="~/Images/slider/Slider_2.jpg" />                

        </div>
        <div>

            <img u="image" src="~/Images/slider/high-ct.jpg" />
        </div>
```

Now the problem is on wider screens images look stretched ( a lot) ? Is there any way I could use percentage/or any other solution for width and height in JSSOR to avoid stretching ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height and width from the CSS. i have put one slider in my gallery in www.bmskpt.in

Comment: Are you using JSSOR ? or slider ?

Answer (score -1):

Solution 1:

Please try $FillMode value 1 or 2 or 4

Solution 2:

Specify 'width: 1280px; height: 415px;' for 'outer container' and 'slides' container.

Specify 'overflow: hidden' and size (what you need) for the parent node of the slider.

Comment: jssor Thanks for your response.

Comment: jssor Thanks for your response. I tried  $FillMode options 1 & 2 before posting here but it did not help. However, Now I tried again after seeing your response and magically it is working ( not totally out of the water though) . It is not stretching but it is choping of top and bottom.I could not see whole picture.I tried option 4 for fillmode and that did not work.

Comment: I did not understand 2nd line of your solution 2 :

Comment: **Specify 'overflow: hidden' and size (what you need) for the parent node of the slider.**.I have 'overflow: hidden' from begin ing and I am not sure of your comment about size